# Get every string before character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two record in table which is as below -:

```
1.123-21
2.123-21-30
```

How to query for all string before certain place of character . Below shown expected output

```
1. 123-21 -> 123 
2. 123-21-30 ->123-21
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: CHARINDEX will find the `-` position. Then use SUBSTRING.

Comment: What is the logic here exactly? You don't actually explain it. You say you want the string before a certain characters, but what is that character. If it's `-`, which are both rows not `123`?

Comment: Assuming something extremely simple: last 3 chars are always CharSpecialDigitDigit :

Comment: SELECT LEFT(Text, LEN() -2)

Comment: EzApi https://elixirforum.com/t/exapi-a-library-for-creating-and-managing-apis-and-their-implementations/6877

Comment: DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(80) = '123-21-30';SELECT LEFT(@Text, LEN(@Text) - 3) --123-21

Comment: EzApi https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/doing-it-with-the-ezapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Vals VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @T(Vals) VALUES ('123-21') , ('123-21-30')

SELECT LEFT(Vals, LEN(Vals) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Vals)) )
FROM @T
```

Comment: thanks....that's what im looking for

Comment: `NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Vals)), 0)` would be wise, in case it can't find it, otherwise you will get errors.